# PHP include_once bug when change file owner and recreate it

Tags: php

First,I create a test script:

```
<?php
//test.php
@unlink('/tmp/abc.php');
var_dump(@include_once('/tmp/abc.php'));
swritefile('/tmp/abc.php','<?php echo 123;');
var_dump(file_exists('/tmp/abc.php'));
var_dump(include_once('/tmp/abc.php'));

function swritefile($filename, $writetext, $openmod='w')
{
    if (@$fp = fopen($filename, $openmod)) {

        flock($fp, 2);

        fwrite($fp, $writetext);

        fclose($fp);

        return true;

    }
}
```

### I have three steps:

#### 1. fetch test.php,out put is:

> bool(false) bool(true) 123int(1)

#### 2. chowner for abc.php `chown vaxili:vaxili /tmp/abc.php`,then fetch test.php.The output is:

> 123int(1) bool(true) bool(true)

#### 3. delete file. `rm /tmp/abc.php` .At last fetch test.php,output is：

> bool(false) bool(true) bool(true)

### It is a bit wired.Where is the output **123** ?

### ENV:

- PHP 7.1
- Nginx

Comment: What is the purpose of this...

Comment: This mosts likely is a caching issue...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Debugging. The OP most likely ran into some issue and tries to create a minimal test case.

Comment: do you already tried clearstatcache(); before every file_exists ?

Comment: I found that is the opcache issue.Because If i disable opcache then I goes well.